# sql query not working properly in nodejs app

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

```js
 payment:(req,res)=>{
        let twothoudand = req.body.twothoudand;
        let fivehundred = req.body.fivehundred;
        let twohundred = req.body.twohundred;
        let hundred = req.body.hundred;
        let fifty = req.body.fifty;
        let twenty = req.body.twenty;
        let ten = req.body.ten;
        let id_list = req.body.sel;

        let sql = "INSERT INTO `paymententry_truck`(`Payment_ID`, `Date`, `2000`, `500`, `200`, `100`, `50`, `20`, `10`) VALUES(NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, '" + twothoudand + "', '" + fivehundred + "','" + twohundred + "','" + hundred + "','" + fifty + "','" + twenty + "','" + ten + "'); `UPDATE` trans1 SET paidStatus = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE trans1.Sr_NO IN(" + id_list + ");"
        let query = conn.query(sql,(err, results)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log(sql);
            }else{
                res.redirect('/');
            }

        });
    }
```

I have One MYSQL query in my nodejs app which is working perfectly if I execute query in phpmyadmin. But when I am sending the same query to the server with node.js application, query is throwing error no 1064

```
INSERT INTO `paymententry_truck`(`Payment_ID`, `Date`, `2000`, `500`, `200`, `100`, `50`, `20`, `10`) VALUES(NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \'7\', \'1\',\'1\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'8\'); UPDATE trans1 SET paidStatus =LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE trans1.Sr_NO IN(10);
```

This is the query which my app sending to server it is working when i paste same query in phpmyadmin, but it's not working when nodejs app is sending the same query to the server.

```
  code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage:
   'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to y
our MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 

\'UPDATE trans1 SET
paidStatus = LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE trans1.Sr_NO IN(10)\' at line 1',
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,


  sql:'INSERT INTO `paymententry_truck`(`Payment_ID`, `Date`, `2000`, `500`, `200`, `100`, `50`, `20`, `10`) VALUES(NULL, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, \'7\', \'1\',\'1\',\'\',\'\',\'\',\'8\'); UPDATE trans1 SET paidStatus =LAST_INSERT_ID() WHERE trans1
.Sr_NO IN(10);' }
```

expected result is to add row in table paymententry_truck with given values and update that last entry number to table trans1 column paidStatus where Sr_No in (10);

Comment: did you allow for multiple statement in configuration? MySQL module doesn't allow multiple statements by default

Comment: you need to execute this query one after the other, cant add both the query in one sql statement

Comment: Please share the exact code you are running

Comment: This same query is working perfectly working when I simply copy pest this query to phpmyadmin

Comment: Dear all I am waiting for solution if any one can resolve my problem thanks in advance

Comment: @NicoHaase I am trying store procedure for this problem but could not made it if any one have any idea about it please help

Comment: Please add the code you are using to the question itself by editing it, not to the comment section. Additionally, have you tried running both queries **seperately** like proposed by Nayan? Most likely, `conn.query` is not able to handle multiple queries at once

Comment: Dear @NicoHaase NayanPatel I think your not understanding My question same query is working in PHPmyadmin but When I am sending this query through node js it is throwing error if reserve words may be because I have used UPDATE query after insert query

Comment: Just to repeat it again: the string does not contain **one single** query, but two. Whatever phpMyAdmin does is not relevant, as this software might be able to do whatever magic it wants - but as long as you do not check **how** PMA handles this, you should try other solutions

Comment: Dear @NicoHaase I found that to execute Multiple query in node js i need to write var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true}); in my mysql connection but I also found that this is vulnerable so if I want to insert some data in one table and than want to update that Id of that last entry to another table how can i do this thanks in advance